# Custom List - add SAVE and SUBMIT buttons

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, custom-form, submit

I have a custom form where I need to include SAVE SUBMIT and CANCEL buttons on the form. Once the form is SUBMITTED it needs to be rendered in-editable where the SAVED form is still able to be edited.

I did have one approach - create a choice field where the user selects if they would like to save or submit. I would then need the text value on the button to change according to selection. On SAVE selection the form is saved to the list items - on SUBMIT choice the list item is moved to another list (administrators list for further processing)

Does anyone have suggestions or solutions.
Please DON'T include InfoPath solutions - we do not use InfoPath.

Comment: By custom form do you mean you can created a webpart/usercontrol/layouts page ? Or you have a custom form created through sp designer in the list ?

Comment: I haven't used a webpart usercontrol layout - I am not familiar with it. I am open to suggestions. Are you able to give me more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If user click on save/submit button then you save the details in list along with this update the choice list value as save/submit in list.

Next You need to create a sharepoint designer 2010 Workflow on this list to move the item to administrator list based the choice field value(if value is submit then move current item to administrator list else no action performed).

I hope this helps to you :)

Comment: Thanks Nagababu. What is trying to be achieved is the ability for a user to save a form - return and complete the form and then submit the form.  I need the list item to have the same ID - will this happen if the list is moved and will it update the moved list when the final version is submitted?

Comment: Hi garvon, we need to do some extra steps.